# Can't Route An MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have tried routes.mapRoute but i can't figure a way in MVC 3 to use it make a root path route to an action. e.g mywebsite.com/party should redirect to mywebsite.com/events/party where events is the controller and party is the action.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Could you post the full list of routes you have?

Comment: yes it is possible.  What do you currently have and what have you tried (show us the code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your existing routes, its hard to give you an exact solution.

One rule to keep in mind:

**MVC will resolve the *first* in your route collection that matches the requested URL**

not necessarily the most specific match.

Make sure you do not have another rule that would also satisfy that route placed earlier in your code, e.g. the routing algorithm might be finding a "party" controller and "index" action because you have a default rule like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

placed before your rule.

You need to put something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PartyRoute",
    "party",
    new { controller = "Events", action = "Party" }
);
```

**BEFORE** any route that might match a URL with just a single parameter

Comment: Thank you! I had the right syntax just put it after the Default one when it should have been before it! Understand routing a bit better now too.

Comment: No problem. I'm sure its caught many out, including me. Steve Sanderson has written a good chapter(s) on routing in his books on MVC - helpful to me http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/06/11/pro-aspnet-mvc-2-framework/

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Events", action = "Index" }
);
```